# Comparing Topologies on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ :

- $\mathcal{T}_1=$ the standard topology
- $\mathcal{T}_2=$ topology of $\mathbb{R}_K$
- $\mathcal{T}_3=$ the finite complement topology
- $\mathcal{T}_4=$ the upper limit topology, having all sets $(a,b]$ as basis
- $\mathcal{T}_5=$ the topology having all sets $(-\infty,a)$ as basis

$\mathbb{R}_K$ is the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with basis elements $(a,b)$ and $(a,b)-K$ where $K=\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

If you do not want to read all that is below, I am writing conclusion :

1. $\mathcal{T}_3\subsetneq\mathcal{T}_1\subsetneq \mathcal{T}_2\subsetneq\mathcal{T}_4$
2. $\mathcal{T}_5\subsetneq\mathcal{T}_1\subsetneq \mathcal{T}_2\subsetneq\mathcal{T}_4$
3. $\mathcal{T}_3$ and $\mathcal{T}_5$ are not comparable.

---

Let $x\in (a,b)$ a basis element in standard topology.. This is also a basis element in $\mathbb{R}_K$ so we have $x\in (a,b)\subset (a,b)$.. So, $\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_1$..

Let $0\in (a,b)-K$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_2$, for any basis element $U$ in  $\mathcal{T}_1$ we have 
$\epsilon>0$ such that $0\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset U$. There exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.
So, we can not have $0\in U\in (a,b)-K$ as $\frac{1}{N}\in U$ but $0\notin \ (a,b)-K$.

So, **$\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_1$ but not the other way.**

---

Let $x\in (a,b)$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_1$. We can not find $ \{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ such that
 $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\subset (a,b)$ as $(a,b)$ is a bounded set where as 
$ \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is unbounded.

Let $x\in U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\}$ a bais element in $\mathcal{T}_3$. We have $1\leq i\leq n$ least such that 
$x<c_i$ then, $x\in (c_{i-1},c_i)\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\}$ if $i>1$
 and $x\in (x-1,c_1)$ if $i=1$. In any case we have a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_1$ containing $x$ and contained
 in $U$.

So, **$\mathcal{T}_1$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_3$ but not the other way.**

---

Let $x\in (a,b)$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_1$ then we have $x\in (a,x]$ a basis element in
$\mathcal{T}_4$ such that $x\in (a,x]\subset (a,b)$.

For $x\in (a,x]$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_4$ we can have no $(c,d)$ such that $x\in (c,d)\subset (a,x]$
as if $d<x$ then $x\notin (c,d)$.

So, **$\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_1$ but not the other way.**

---

Let $x\in (a,b)$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_1$ then there can be no open set $(-\infty,a)$ containing $x$
and contained in $(c,d)$ as $(c,d)$ is bounded where as $(-\infty,a)$ is unbounded.

Let $x\in (-\infty,a)$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_5$ then we have $x\in (x-1,a)$ a basis element
in $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $(x-1,a)\subset (-\infty,a)$..

So, **$\mathcal{T}_1$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$ but not the other way.**

---

**$\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_3$ but not the other way clear.**

---

Let $x\in (a,b)$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_2$ then we have $x\in (a,x]$ a basis element in
$\mathcal{T}_4$ such that $x\in (a,x]\subset (a,b)$.

Let $x\in (a,b)-K$ another basis element in $\mathcal{T}_2$. We can assume that $(a,b)\cap K\neq \emptyset$. We then have $\frac{1}{n+1}<x<\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ then we have $x\in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})\subset (a,b)-K$.

Let $x\in (a,x]$ a basis element in $\mathcal{T}_4$. We know that $\mathcal{T}_1$ is not finer than $\mathcal{T}_4$.. So, if at all $\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than  $\mathcal{T}_2$ we must have $x\in (a,b)-K\subset (a,x]$ which would again mean that $x<b$ and $b<x$.. Contradiction.

So, **$\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_2$ but not the other way.**

---

**$\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$ but not the other way. Clear. $\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_3$ but not the other way. Clear.**

---

**$\mathcal{T}_3$ is not finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$ is clear.**

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ (wlog we can assume that $x_1<x_2$) and that $x\in (x_1,x_2)$
 then any open set containing $x$ of the form $(-\infty,a)$ contains $x_1$
as $x_1<x$. So, **$\mathcal{T}_3$ is not  finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$.**

**$\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$ but not the other way. Clear.**

Let me know if these justifications are correct...

Comment: Why negative vote??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have the right ideas, and good on you for showing proper work! Some remarks:

You do not need to consider the topologies 1 and 4 separately, this will already fall out ot considering 1 and 2 and 2 and 4. If we have strict inclusion there, then a fortiori we will have it for 1 and 4, no need for a separate proof. Similary with 2 and 5, e.g.

What about 4 and 5? You just say "clear" but some argument seems in order.

You seem to assume that $x_1 < x_2$, because the open interval $(x_1,x_2)$ is non-empty (in 3 vs 5)? A bit sloppy.

Comment: I can arrange the elements so that $x_1<x_2$.. Can't I?

Comment: As $\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_2$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$, we see that $\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$. Suppose $\mathcal{T}_5$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_4$, as $\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_2$, then this would imply $\mathcal{T}_5$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_2$ which is not true. So, $\mathcal{T}_4$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_5$ but not the other way.

Comment: Yes, if you arrange them that way, you have to say so, not implicitly assume so.

Comment: Yes I agree....